# Should we use thread pool for long running threads?

Tags: threadpool, java-threads

Should we use a thread pool for long running threads or start our own threads? Is there some design pattern?

Comment: Pools are typical when you create them quite often.

Comment: The creation is not often, but are there other thread management benefits which thread pool implementations provide OOTB, which would be useful? Is there any harm in using a thread pool for long running threads?

Comment: Not sure, maybe this article helps: http://www.journaldev.com/1069/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor

Comment: All modern Java application servers (Weblogic, Glassfish, etc) use  thread pools. That should tell us something :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it depends. There is no hard and fast rule saying that you should always employ thread pools.

Thread pools offer two main things:

1. Delegated creation/reuse of threads.
2. Back-pressure

IMO, it's the back-pressure property that's interesting, but often the most poorly understood. Your machine runs on a limited set of resources. If you have (say) 8 CPU cores and they are all busy working, you would like to signal that in some way that adding more work (submitting more tasks) isn't going to help, at least not in terms of latency.

This is the reason `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` implementations allow you to specify a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` of your choice. When this queue grows full, invoking threads will block until the thread pool has managed to complete tasks in progress.

Whether or not to have long-running threads inside the thread pool depends on what it's doing. If the thread is constantly busy (meaning it will never complete) then it will always occupy a slot in the thread pool, which is kind of pointless.

Regarding delegated creation/reuse of threads; maybe you could have two pools, one for long-running tasks and one for other tasks. Or perhaps a long-running thread pool with one single slot, this will prevent two long-running tasks from running at the same time, provided that is what you want.

As you can see, there is no single good answer. It really boils down to what you are trying to achieve and how you want to use the resources at hand.